# Simon Says counter not working properly

Tags: java

I'm coding a Simon Says game that is supposed to keep track of how many times the user successfully completes the task. The code runs, but the output is incorrect. The expected output is 4 but my code puts out 8.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimonSays 
{
    public static void main (String [] args) 
    {
        String simonPattern = "";
        String userPattern = "";
        int userScore = 0;
        int i = 0;

        userScore = 0;
        simonPattern = "RRGBRYYBGY";
        userPattern  = "RRGBBRYBGY";

        char s;
        char u;

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            s = simonPattern.charAt(i);
            u = userPattern.charAt(i);
            if (s == u) 
            {
                userScore = userScore + 1;
                continue;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("userScore: " + userScore);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is java - not javascript!

Comment: And why 4? When 8 characters match?

Comment: I apologize if I misidentified the language, I'm new to this. What is the proper name for this language of code?

Comment: And what is `userScore = userScore;` for?

Comment: It should only count the first 4 matches and break when the user input does not match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said in your question **output is 4 but my code puts out 8.** You want how many continuous character matched from the start of the String.

It means you want to `break` the loop just after conscative

```
    simonPattern = "RRGBRYYBGY";
    userPattern  = "RRGBBRYBGY"; //Index 4 have different Characters .


if (s == u) 
   {
    userScore = userScore + 1; //add your counter 1 at each time character matched.
     continue;   //directly move to loop control statement.
  }
```

this piece of code will check till the last element present in the `String` and your counter will repeatedly increases till the last element of the `String`.

> try this code. will work

```
if (s != u) 
           {
           break; //this will break your loop in just after character doesn't matched.
          }

       ++userScore; // Increase your counter if matched.
```

Answer (score 3):

So I assume you go through the characters and when the first time the characters don't match, then you will consider it "failing" and only count the preceding matches.

So in this case, you can use

```
if (s != u) {
  break;
}
```

to break out of the loop; otherwise, just increment the count.

I don't like to use `break` personally, but would just write a function to return the count when the characters don't match.

Answer (score 0):

This was in a zyBooks lesson. This is how I solved it.

```
for (i = 0; i < simonPattern.length(); ++i) {
     if((simonPattern.charAt(i)) == (userPattern.charAt(i))) {
        userScore += 1;
     }
     else {
        break;
     }
  }
```